# Metodo para editar no funciona ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web de un concesionario de autos, tengo una vista para editar el objeto de tipo Automovil que tiene los siguientes parametros: modelo, año de fabricacion, color, precio, transmision, combustible, marca, modelo, categoria, estado, extra y foto.

Generé mi controlador usando MVC y Entity Framework, sin embargo, no modifica ninguno de los datos, solo modifica la foto.

**Metodo para editar**

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Automovil automovil, HttpPostedFileBase archivo)
    {
        if(automovil ==null){
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        if (TryUpdateModel(automovil, "", new string[] { "idAutomovil,modelo,año,color,precio,informacionExtra,idMarca,idCategoria,idCombustible,idEstado,idTransmision" }))
        {
            try
            {
                if(archivo != null && archivo.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    if(automovil.archivos.Any(i => i.tipo == FileType.Imagen))
                    {
                        db.archivo.Remove(automovil.archivos.First(i => i.tipo == FileType.Imagen));
                    }
                    var imagen = new Archivo
                    {
                        nombre = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(archivo.FileName),
                        tipo = FileType.Imagen,
                        ContentType = archivo.ContentType
                    };
                    using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(archivo.InputStream))
                    {
                        imagen.contenido = reader.ReadBytes(archivo.ContentLength);
                    }
                    automovil.archivos = new List<Archivo> { imagen };
                }
                db.Entry(automovil).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch(RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
            }
        }
        ViewBag.idCategoria = new SelectList(db.categoria, "idCategoria", "nombre", automovil.idCategoria);
        ViewBag.idCombustible = new SelectList(db.combustible, "idCombustible", "nombre", automovil.idCombustible);
        ViewBag.idEstado = new SelectList(db.estado, "idEstado", "nombre", automovil.idEstado);
        ViewBag.idMarca = new SelectList(db.marca, "idMarca", "nombre", automovil.idMarca);
        ViewBag.idTransmision = new SelectList(db.transmision, "idTransmision", "nombre", automovil.idTransmision);
        return View(automovil);
    }
```

Como mencioné antes, lo único que me edita es la imagen del automovil, no los otros datos.

Debugueando el programa pude notar que al editar algunos campos de Automovil aparecen como null.

**Debug**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería me pudieran ayudar para ver que es lo que tengo que corregir en mi controlador para que reciba esos datos.

EDIT

**Codigo de la Vista**

```
@model Autoventas_IN6AV.Models.Automovil

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Editar";
}

<h2>Editar Información</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Automovil", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Automovil</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idAutomovil)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.modelo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.modelo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.modelo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.año, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.año)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.año)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.color, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.color)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.color)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.precio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.precio)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.precio)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.informacionExtra, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.informacionExtra)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.informacionExtra)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idMarca, "Marca", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("idMarca", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idMarca)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idCategoria, "Categoria", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("idCategoria", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idCategoria)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idCombustible, "Combustible", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("idCombustible", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idCombustible)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idEstado, "Estado", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("idEstado", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idEstado)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idTransmision, "Transmisión", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("idTransmision", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idTransmision)
            </div>
        </div>

        @if (Model.archivos.Any(i => i.tipo == FileType.Imagen))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="control-label col-md-2"><strong>Foto Actual</strong></span>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <img src="~/Archivo/ObtenerArchivo?id=@Model.archivos.First(i => i.tipo == FileType.Imagen).idArchivo" alt="Imagen Automóvil."/>
                    </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Foto", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" id="Imagen" name="archivo" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar al listado", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

EDIT

**Codigo del Modelo**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Autoventas_IN6AV.Models
{
    public class Automovil
    {
        [Key]
        public int idAutomovil { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Modelo"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Este dato es obligatorio.")]
        public String modelo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Año de Fabricación"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Este dato es obligatorio.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime año { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Color"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Este dato es obligatorio.")]
        public String color { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Precio"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Este dato es obligatorio."), DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public String precio { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Extras"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Este dato es obligatorio.")]
        public String informacionExtra { get; set; }

        public int idMarca { get; set; }
        public virtual Marca marca { get; set; }

        public int idCategoria { get; set; }
        public virtual Categoria categoria { get; set; }

        public int idCombustible { get; set; }
        public virtual Combustible combustible { get; set; }

        public int idEstado { get; set; }
        public virtual Estado estado { get; set; }

        public int idTransmision { get; set; }
        public virtual Transmision transmision { get; set; }

        public virtual Reservacion reservacion { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Archivo> archivos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código de la vista también? Ayudaría a diagnosticar el error.

Comment: Lo había olvidado. Ya lo agregué.

Comment: El código del modelo también, eso cambió lo que pensaba del problema.

Comment: Modelo agregado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según tu modelo, esto es normal.  De la vista solo vas a recibir el id de la entidades relacionadas, no hay problema que por ejemplo `combustible` sea `null` siempre y cuando `idCombustible` esté asignado.  Entity Framework actualizará correctamente la entidad si una de las dos propiedades está asignada.  MVC no carga automáticamente las entidades relacionadas por id, no tiene información para saber cómo.

También hay un error en la línea de `TryUpdateModel`, el valor:

**Mal**:

```
new string[] { "idAutomovil,modelo,año,color,precio,informacionExtra,idMarca,idCategoria,idCombustible,idEstado,idTransmision" }
```

**Correcto**:

```
new string[] { "idAutomovil", "modelo", "año", "color", "precio", "informacionExtra", "idMarca", "idCategoria", "idCombustible", "idEstado", "idTransmision" }
```

Comment: También me fijé en eso, que recibe (por ejemplo) idContenido y contenido. Entonces, en mi modelo solo tengo que tener el id de la propiedad a la que hago referencia? No me causará problema a la hora de que se carguen los datos  a la dropdownlist?

Comment: No va a interferir con el dropdownlist porque los textos ya los estás cargando directamente de la base de datos cuando haces `ViewBag.idCategoria = new SelectList(db.categoria, "idCategoria", "nombre", automovil.idCategoria);`

Comment: Ok, para confirmar, este es mi modelo Automovil, solo tengo que dejar el id de las llaves foraneas, no es necesario `public virtual Ejemplo ejemplo`? [http://i.imgur.com/NcbXfzl.jpg]

Comment: Ohh, eso cambia las cosas, pensé que estabas guardando la descripción pero tienes la referencia a la entidad, eso está bien (aunque es opcional).  Lo que significa que es esperado que esos valores sean `null` ya que solo estás asignando el id, pero EF no debería tener problema en actualizarlo.  ¿Los valores de marca o categoría se borran? eso no debería pasar

Comment: Aclarando, no hay problema que esas propiedades sean `null` si es que asignas el FK.

Comment: Como puedo ver si esos valores se borran? El metodo para editar estaba funcionando bien hasta que implementé el `try` para verificar el archivo.

Comment: Cuando dices que no funciona, significa que cuando cargas nuevamente la entidad desde base de datos, ¿los valores no han cambiado? a pesar de seleccionar diferentes opciones en los dropdown.

Comment: Así es, selecciono diferentes valores en los dropdown y cambio datos en los textbox y no se guardan los nuevos valores.

Comment: ¿Y está entrando al bloque de `TryUpdateModel`? veo que tienes un error ahí, en lugar de `new string[] { "idAutomovil,modelo,año,..."}` debería ser un *string* por cada propiedad, es decir: `new string[] { "idAutomovil", "modelo" , "año", ...}`

Comment: Ese era mi error, cada propiedad tenia que ir en un string.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayuda y el tiempo que invertiste tratando de encontrar la solución.

Comment: No hay problema :)